# How do I efficiently replace the time portion of datetime values in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a number of datetime values. I'd like to change the time portion of these to a specific time that is the same for all observations in the dataframe, but preserve the date portion of the datetime.

I can do this with a single datetime, using the `datetime` package and the `.replace()` function:

```
import datetime

dt_test=datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17,21,30,15)
print(dt_test)

dt_test=dt_test.replace(hour=6,minute=0,second=0)

print(dt_test)
```

Which returns:

```
2020-05-17 21:30:15
2020-05-17 06:00:00
```

I feel like I should be able to use the `.dt` operator to apply this to the whole column, but receive an error when I attempt to do so.

```
import pandas as pd
dates=[
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,2,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,3,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,3,6,0,0),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,3,12,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,1,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,2,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,4,4,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,2,12,30,15),
    datetime.datetime(2018,1,4,12,30,15),
]
ids=list(range(len(dates)))

df=pd.DataFrame(zip(ids,dates),columns=['id','date_time'])
df
```

Returns:

```
    id  date_time
0   0   2018-01-01 04:30:15
1   1   2018-01-02 04:30:15
2   2   2018-01-03 04:30:15
3   3   2018-01-03 06:00:00
4   4   2018-01-03 12:30:15
5   5   2018-01-01 04:30:15
6   6   2018-01-02 04:30:15
7   7   2018-01-04 04:30:15
8   8   2018-01-02 12:30:15
9   9   2018-01-04 12:30:15
```

Where the 'date_time' column is dtype: datetime64[ns], as desired (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347513/how-do-i-efficiently-apply-pandas-timestamp-functions-to-a-full-dataframe-column) question).

I then attempt to use pandas' [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html) function with the `.dt` operator:

```
df['date_time'].dt.replace(hour=6,minute=0,second=0)
df
```

But I receive the following error (using jupyter, if that matters):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-65a7bb8c3365> in <module>
----> 1 df['date_time'].dt.replace(hour=6,minute=0,second=0)
      2 df

AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

How can I go about efficiently replacing the time portion of a datetime variable in a pandas column?

Note: I found [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) question that can set the time to midnight for all dates, but the time does matter for me and is unlikely to be midnight.

Comment: @MrFuppes Even though I did not accept it (I had two acceptable answers), I did think your answer added value and showed another way to do things (both another way to use pd.Timedelta() and use of the floor() function. Feel free to repost it - I at least learned from it. Showing the results of your benchmark would also add additional value if you'd like to include those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `hour=0, minute=0, second=0`, Pandas has an built-in:

```
df['date_time'].dt.normalize()
```

and then you can shift:

```
df['date_time'].dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('01:02:03')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I noted that at the end of my question - I found this, but the time does matter for my problem. Is there a way to use this, then say add X hours/mins/seconds to the normalized time?

Answer (score 3):

Besides using `normalize()`as @QuangHoang shows in his answer, you can  `floor` the timestamps to the day (i.e. giving you also the date with H:M:S all set to zero), and add a timedelta:

```
df['date_time'].dt.floor('d') + pd.Timedelta(hours=6)
```

Another option would be to use `replace` by applying a `lambda`:

```
df['date_time'] = df['date_time'].apply(lambda t: t.replace(hour=6,minute=0,second=0))
```

Performance-wise, the iterative `apply` is significantly slower for larger series sizes:
[image]

Interestingly, flooring to the day has a slight advantage over the normalize method in this benchmark for sizes > 10k elements. And I think `floor` is more readable (my personal taste) since there is no general definition what `normalize` means.

---

Benchmark: Python 3.8.7 x86-64, pandas 1.2.1. Code (see also [simple benchmark](https://github.com/MSeifert04/simple_benchmark)):

```
import pandas as pd
from simple_benchmark import benchmark

timeseries = pd.Series([
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,1,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,2,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,3,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,3,6,0,0),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,3,12,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,1,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,2,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,4,4,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,2,12,30,15),
    pd.Timestamp(2018,1,4,12,30,15),
])

add = pd.Timedelta(hours=6)

def floor_day(s):
    return s.dt.floor('d') + add

def normalize_day(s):
    return s.dt.normalize() + add

def apply_replace(s):
    return s.apply(lambda t: t.replace(hour=6,minute=0,second=0))

funcs = [floor_day, normalize_day, apply_replace]
arguments = {i*timeseries.size: timeseries.repeat(i) for i in [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]}
argument_name = 'series_size'
b = benchmark(funcs, arguments, argument_name)
b.plot()
```

Comment: This is also good. I was surprised by your statement and assumed that `.apply()` would not be the way to go. But you are correct, at least for this toy example. That said, when I increased the dataframe size (added `*1000` to the definition of `dates`), the `floor` method was the quickest, followed very closely by `normalize`. The `.apply()` approach was about 90 times slower for me.

Comment: @amquack: yup, I didn't check for large Series. Always good to cross-check for your own requirements.

Comment: `apply` is not vectorized so in general should be avoided. On small data, the performances are not so difference, sometimes even in favor of `apply`, because of the vectorization overheads (memory distribution, thread managements, etc), but for larger data, the differences should be significant as @amquack pointed out.